# jQuery.Deferred exception: Kendo is not defined ReferenceError: Kendo is not defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

I am trying to populate data to a kendo datagrid using MVC5. Although ,I have referenced the javascript files correctly, I get the error message jQuery.Deferred exception: Kendo is not defined ReferenceError: Kendo is not defined.

When i see in the console window, the error is on the following line

```
  var carsDataSource = new Kendo.Data.DataSource({ data: cars });
```

Please see the code below

The head section in the layout mage

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
    @*<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>*@
</head>
```

**DataGridController**

```
 public class DataGridController : Controller
    {
        // GET: DataGrid
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Index.html**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<div id="cars"></div>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {


        var cars = [
            { year: 2012, make: "Ferrari", model: "California" },
            { year: 2013, make: "Ferrari", model: "458 Italia" },
            { year: 2014, make: "Lambhorhini", model: "California" },
            { year: 2015, make: "Porche", model: "California" },
            { year: 2015, make: "Audi", model: "A7" },
            { year: 2016, make: "Mercedez", model: "E350" },
            { year: 2016, make: "Nisan", model: "California" },
            { year: 2015, make: "Ford", model: "California" },
            { year: 2014, make: "Jaguar", model: "California" },
            { year: 2015, make: "McLaren", model: "California" },
            { year: 2013, make: "Ferrari", model: "California" },
            { year: 2011, make: "Mercedez", model: "C200" },
            { year: 2017, make: "Mercedez", model: "GLA" },
        ];

        var carsDataSource = new Kendo.Data.DataSource({ data: cars });
        carsDataSource.read();

        $("#cars").kendoGrid({ dataSource: carsDataSource });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you have mis-spelled the constructor
- as well as look like you have commented out kendo.all.min.js javascript file
- The major reason when this error show up is misconfiguration of resources needed **look into the running sample provided and see if you are missing some kendo related javascript file and add it into your bundle** . Most probably there is something wrong with the included resources.

Below is the minimum required configuration of kendo grid

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also unless you set the grid auto bind to false you don't need to initiate a read() function. look into this documentation [read method of kendo grid](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-read)

Here is live version of your code .

Dojo sample here [working dojo sample](http://dojo.telerik.com/iriPe)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>
<body>

<div id="cars"></div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var carsList = [
            { year: 2012, make: "Ferrari", model: "California" },
            { year: 2013, make: "Ferrari", model: "458 Italia" },
            { year: 2014, make: "Lambhorhini", model: "California" },
            { year: 2015, make: "Porche", model: "California" },
            { year: 2015, make: "Audi", model: "A7" },
            { year: 2016, make: "Mercedez", model: "E350" },
            { year: 2016, make: "Nisan", model: "California" },
            { year: 2015, make: "Ford", model: "California" },
            { year: 2014, make: "Jaguar", model: "California" },
            { year: 2015, make: "McLaren", model: "California" },
            { year: 2013, make: "Ferrari", model: "California" },
            { year: 2011, make: "Mercedez", model: "C200" },
            { year: 2017, make: "Mercedez", model: "GLA" },
        ];

          var carsDataSource =  new kendo.data.DataSource({data: carsList});             

          carsDataSource.read();

          $("#cars").kendoGrid({ dataSource: carsDataSource });  

    });

</script>
```